# HP Block Storage using jclouds Template

Tags: cloud, jclouds, hp-cloud-services

following the docs here:
http://code.google.com/p/jclouds/wiki/EBS
i see how to attach an EBS volume to a newly provisioned ec2 instance.
does anybody know if there is an equivalent to this for HP Block Storage? or Rackspace Block Storage?

im looking for a way to specify that i want a volume attached to my VM in the template, and let jclouds to the rest...i dont want to call specific cloud storage API's.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Rackspace the place you want to start is [Getting Started: The Rackspace Open Cloud](http://www.jclouds.org/documentation/quickstart/rackspace/).

Specifically for Cloud Block Storage you'll want to start at [The Examples](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-examples/tree/master/rackspace) and then checkout the [cloudblockstorage package](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-examples/tree/master/rackspace/src/main/java/org/jclouds/examples/rackspace/cloudblockstorage). The [CreateVolumeAndAttach.java](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-examples/blob/master/rackspace/src/main/java/org/jclouds/examples/rackspace/cloudblockstorage/CreateVolumeAndAttach.java) example might be exactly what you're looking for.

There is no portable abstraction for block storage in jclouds like there is for compute and blobstore (aka object storage) so you won't be able to do this via a template. But the code above will work with any OpenStack powered cloud.

BTW, the code.google.com site for jclouds is well out of date and shouldn't be used. The place to go is [jclouds Documentation](http://www.jclouds.org/documentation/).

Comment: So you are saying the Cinder API should work with HP. but the example for Rackspace is specifying a specific Block Storage provider ("rackspace-cloudblockstorage-us"), what is the provider if i want to use this with HP? also, if i want a Block storage API for ec2(not via template), should i use the ElasticBlockStorageClient? or is there some way to make the Cinder API work for EBS as well? thanks so much!

Comment: I answered the HP part over in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598793/cinder-api-using-jclouds/14631441#14631441 You won't be able to use the Cinder API with EBS. You'll need to use ElasticBlockStorageClient but I'm not at all familiar with it.